# Node.js REST webservice with wrong Content-Type

Tags: node.js, rest, fastify

I'm developing a REST webservice in Node.js, with fastify framework, designed to respond to a specific client.

This is how the client calls my webservice:

```http
POST /myws/scan HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.io
User-Agent: AGENT
Content-Length: 45
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"FIELD1":"testvalue","FIELD2":True,"FIELD3":90}
```

As you can see the Content-Type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but the request payload is in "application/json" format.
I can't change the client, so I have to adapt my webservice to manage this kind of calls.
I tried with @fastify/formbody package but I receive an error because I think it expects the request body in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format.

I tried also with this code:

```
app.addContentTypeParser('application/x-www-form-urlencoded', function (req, body, done) {
    try {
      var json = JSON.parse(body)
      done(null, json)
    } catch (err) {
      err.statusCode = 400
      done(err, undefined)
    }
  })
```

but I have a JSON deserializing error.
How I can manage these kind of calls and which is the best way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you can add a middleware an update your `req` object to have `content-type` header with value `application/json` before content type parser touches it?

Comment: “*I have a JSON deserializing error*” What does the full stack trace of this error look like? Is what you’re receiving even valid JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` is a stream.

You need to add the `parseAs` option:

```
fastify.addContentTypeParser(
  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  { parseAs: 'string' },
  function (req, body, done) {
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(body)
      done(null, json)
    } catch (err) {
      err.statusCode = 400
      done(err, undefined)
    }
  }
)
```

I would check the first char before running the `JSON.parse` and I would use https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-json-parse (as Fastify does under the hood)

Comment: this solution works but I had to change "True" in "true". This was the reason of Json parsing error.